# How to connect to ActiveMQ Artemis using JWT tokens?

Tags: jwt, activemq-artemis

We have .NET Client applications set up to connect to Apache ActiveMQ Artemis using credentials configured in `broker.xml` file. We have newer Web clients that need to connect, but we prefer to use JWT tokens to authenticate with it. From the documentation I'm learning that we'd need to write a custom security plugin to do that and I'm seeking some guidance on how to go about it.

If not for connecting to ActiveMQ Artemis via amqps and pasing credentials, what are some other ways available?

Comment: What client library are you using to connect? Does it support passing JWT tokens? What protocol does it use?

Comment: Also, what credentials are you configuring in `broker.xml`? That doesn't sound quite right.

Comment: I use 
  <cluster-user>XXXXX</cluster-user>
        <cluster-password>XXXXX</cluster-password>

Comment: Your client applications are using the values assigned in `cluster-user` and `cluster-password`? Those values are only for brokers to use when connecting with another broker in the same cluster. Also, you didn't answer the questions in my first comment.

Comment: Yes, Our Clients are using values assigned in cluster-user and cluster-password. for the new web application, we are using this client - https://www.npmjs.com/package/rhea#api and it does look like it uses amqp protocol to connect.

Comment: I **strongly** recommend you discontinue using the values assigned in `cluster-user `and `cluster-password` from your client applications. You're compromising your security by using those values. You should create an individual user account for each application, assign them roles appropriately, and configure `security-settings` in `broker.xml` so they have the only the permissions that they absolutely need to function properly.

Comment: Does the client you're using support passing JWT tokens?

Comment: It doesn't look like so. Its a library called Rhea and its Typescript based. We developed a custom library that uses AMQPNet Lite for our legacy desktop application that connects to artemis and it doesn't support JWT Tokens either.

Answer (score 1):

Most messaging protocols and client APIs explicitly support username & password credentials and nothing else. JWT, as the name suggests, was developed for *web* use-cases which don't necessarily apply directly to messaging use-cases.

I recommend you investigate certificate-based auth instead as that is readily supported.

Comment: Isn't there a way we could add a custom plugin that can basically do what we intend to which is to take a JWT token and validate it and help establish connection with artemis?